# Status 404 – Not Found on @post annotation with RESTFul API

Tags: java, xml, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have given the configuration details in java file, When I try to access the URL I get status 404 error.
Couldn't find where I am going wrong. The URL that I tried to access is `http://localhost:8080/foodCourt/webapi/foods`.
Please help to resolve the code. 
Herewith I am sharing the code details. This error I get when I use `@Post` annotation.Please find the details for web.xml file. I give webapi in the file for url pattern.I have provided the necessary jar files that includes hibernate, jersey, jboss

```
@ApplicationPath("webapi")
public class AplicationConfig extends Application { 
   @Override
   public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() { 
          Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>(); 
          addRestResourceClasses(resources); 
          return resources; 
   }
   private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {  
           resources.add(resources.Foods.class);
   } 
}

@XmlRootElement
public class FoodCourt {
    private int foodCourtId;
    private String foodCourtName;
    private int seatingCapacity;
    private int votes;
    public int getFoodCourtId() {
        return foodCourtId;
    }
    public void setFoodCourtId(int foodCourtId) {
        this.foodCourtId = foodCourtId;
    }
    public String getFoodCourtName() {
        return foodCourtName;
    }
    public void setFoodCourtName(String foodCourtName) {
        this.foodCourtName = foodCourtName;
    }
    public int getSeatingCapacity() {
        return seatingCapacity;
    }
    public void setSeatingCapacity(int seatingCapacity) {
        this.seatingCapacity = seatingCapacity;
    }
    public int getVotes() {
        return votes;
    }
    public void setVotes(int votes) {
        this.votes = votes;
    }
}


@Path("/foods")
public class Foods {
    private Foods()
    {}
    private FoodDAO fooddao = new FoodCourtDAOImple();
    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/xml,application/json")
    public Response fooddetails(FoodCourt foodDTO) throws Exception
    {
        int id=fooddao.addFoodDetails(foodDTO);
        System.out.println(id);
        return Response.status(201).entity(id).build();
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="FoodCourt")
public class FoodCourtEntity {
    @Id
    private int foodCourtId;
    private String foodCourtName;
    private int seatingCapacity;
    private int votes;
    public int getFoodCourtId() {
        return foodCourtId;
    }
    public void setFoodCourtId(int foodCourtId) {
        this.foodCourtId = foodCourtId;
    }
    public String getFoodCourtName() {
        return foodCourtName;
    }
    public void setFoodCourtName(String foodCourtName) {
        this.foodCourtName = foodCourtName;
    }
    public int getSeatingCapacity() {
        return seatingCapacity;
    }
    public void setSeatingCapacity(int seatingCapacity) {
        this.seatingCapacity = seatingCapacity;
    }
    public int getVotes() {
        return votes;
    }
    public void setVotes(int votes) {
        this.votes = votes;
    }
}

public class FoodCourtDAOImple implements FoodDAO {
    Session session;
    SessionFactory factory;
    @Override
    public int addFoodDetails(FoodCourt foodcourt) throws Exception      {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int foodCourtId=0;
        try
        {
            factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
            session = factory.openSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            FoodCourt foodDTO=foodcourt;
            FoodCourtEntity foodEntity=new FoodCourtEntity();
            foodEntity.setFoodCourtId(foodDTO.getFoodCourtId());
            foodEntity.setFoodCourtName(foodDTO.getFoodCourtName());
            foodEntity.setSeatingCapacity(foodDTO.getSeatingCapacity());
            foodEntity.setVotes(foodDTO.getVotes());
            foodCourtId=(int) session.save(foodEntity);
            return foodCourtId; 
        }catch (HibernateException exception) {
            throw new Exception(exception.getMessage());
        }
         finally {
            if (session != null || session.isOpen()) {
                session.close();
            }
         }
    }
}


public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory factory;
    private HibernateUtil() {
    }
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

        Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure();
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfg.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        return factory;
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
see implementation details   http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>org.aarthi.rest.messenger</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: How is your app deployed? Where does this `/foodCourt/` path comes from? Is this your app context path on your application server?

Comment: Consider marking the most helpful answer as correct to help other users with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see any mapping for the controller, try with the following url:

```
 http://localhost:8080/webapi/foods
```

Answer (score 0):

Try once by changing  @ApplicationPath("webapi") to  @ApplicationPath("/webapi")